# Replace connection in report's datasource with ReportingServicesTools

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have different shared datasource connections for dev/prod/local in our `SSRS` solution. When we deploy the report to the report server we need to replace datasource to the proper one. For example while I am developing report I am using `ds_local` shared connection, but before I deploy it to the dev server, I need to change it to dev. Nothing complex but developers usually forgets to update this connection and commit the report with the wrong datasource. I wrote powershell script that would automatically replace the datasource to the one we need. For that I needed to write quite a lot of code, update ReportServer database tables and so on. Then I've found very nice powershell module that actually is supposed to do everything that I did but in much easier way: [RportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools).

It seems to work fine, but I can't get how can I implement following scenario:

1. Find the shared datasource that is on our reporting server using it's path+name;
2. Replace the used datasource in the report with the one I've taken from the #1

I've found following functions:
`Get-RsDataSource` and `Set-RsItemDataSource` but as I understand right now that the first one get's just the information about the datasource and 2nd one expects the datasource object. Is there any way to retrieve shared datasource as datasource object or the only way I can do is to create the new datasource manually?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar. I ended up directly updating the XML of the rdl files. In your case, I would probably download the RDL file, update the XML and push it back. My case was a bit different, but here's the code I ended up using to take a bunch of reports we got from a vendor, update the data source and upload them to SSRS.

```
#Install-Module -name ReportingServicesTools

$reportPath = "C:\Path\to\rdls"
$dataSourceReference = "theNameoftheSharedDataSourceOnSSRS"
$rsFolder = "/Path/to/destination/folder/on/SSRS"
$rsURI = "https://SSRSsite/reportserver"


get-childitem -Path $reportPath -Filter *.rdl -Recurse | % {
    $curItem = $_.FullName
    $xml = [xml](get-content $curItem)
    $xml.Report.DataSources.DataSource.DataSourceReference = $dataSourceReference
    $xml.Save($curItem)
    Write-RsFolderContent -Path $_.DirectoryName -RsFolder $rsFolder -ReportServerUri $rsURI -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Output $_.FullName
}
```

There's also Get-RSItemDataSource. It might be able to do what you are trying to do directly.